# Mongoengine - how to get database name?

Tags: mongoengine

I am using mongoengine v0.15.0. How to fetch the name of the database connected to? Of course, I would have supplied the name in the uri string. But, is there a way to query mongo and find it?

Thanks,
Harsha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the information about the DB connection created in the mongoengine can be found by calling get_db() which returns a `pymongo.database.Database` object. Then you can access the database name in the attribute `name`. Here is an example.

```
from mongoengine.connection import get_db, connect

connect("test_db")

# Then, somewhere where you want to get the DB name
db = get_db()
print("Database name: ", db.name)
```

The output:

```
Database name: test_db
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.